# SQL: paging without repetition from an dynamic table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL table called `articles` from which I load rows divided by pages. My SQL is

```
SELECT ...
ORDER BY $orderCol DESC
LIMIT $offset, $numPerPage
```

On page one the limit is `0, $numPerPage`, page two it's `$numPerPage, 2 * $numPerPage` etc.

**The problem:** When a new row is inserted before page 2 is loaded, the last article from page 1 will be the first article in page 2 etc. How can I avoid this?

I thought about adding a `WHERE` clause to select articles starting from the last `$orderCol`, but this field is not unique (it's a date in my case) so I'll miss articles with the same value here. The primary index is also a problem because it's not ordered the same way as `$orderCol`

It's not necessary that the newly added row will appear at any point. This will require a refresh.

Comment: I think the only way to avoid this would be to cache the entire result set, which is not very nice.  But, playing the devil's advocate, what is wrong with having that new record appear on page 2?  I would prefer to get accurate, up-to-date information in my query results.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't mind if the NEW entry will appear on page 2, but I don't want to display the same entry twice

Comment: You _won't_ display the same entry twice if each page is done via a new query.  Yes, the same item may seem to appear "twice," but this is how most web pages behave.  Just look at Stack Overflow's new question page.  Users are used to this behavior already.

Comment: My UI is an infinite scroll, It looks bad

Comment: You need to re-calculate the variable to reflect the new entries made in table.

Comment: @Rahul you mean count the number of new rows and increase the offset?

Comment: absolutely Yes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is to add a condition in the WHERE clause.

Rahul suggested that I should count the new articles since the previous query and add it to the offset. This was tricky because since counting the articles would imply that I can run a query that stops where the previous one began, and if I had a way to do that, I could've just as easily make the second query start where the first *ended*.

So I realized I needed a new column. I called it `date-added` and the new condition is, `date-added < $time-of-first-query` for all subsequent queries. Then, the offset is just the number of articles written so far.

Answer (score 1):

Your `LIMIT` should be something like below rather. Define a `$page` variable which will change from `1 .. no.of pages` you want.

```
LIMIT $offset, $page * $numPerPage
```

OK, in that case you will have to re-calculate your `$pages` and `$numPerPage` variable every time (on refresh) and define the paging accordingly.

Comment: That's what I'm doing just with different var names

Comment: You have to refresh your PHP page after each query.  Are you really not doing that?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I doubt that too. to me feels like Op probably misunderstanding the way pagination works in general.

Comment: @Rahul I don't know if you understood the question. The page has an infinite scroll so I don't reload the page. If I set the offset to correspond to the last article in the previous "page", and by the time the user scrolls a new article is added, I'm going to have duplicates